# Given a string, check if search term matches the beginning of any substring

Tags: java, regex

Given this string:

```
"KING-SIZE (KS)"
```

These search terms should return **true** for matching the given string:

```
"k", "ki", "kin", "king", "s", "si", "siz", "size", "-size", "(k", "(ks", "(ks)", "ks", "king-size"
```

These search terms should return **false** for matching the given string:

```
"i", "in", "ing", "iz", "ize"
```

I'm coding in Java and at first I thought I'd use

```
"KING-SIZE (KS)".contains(searchTerm)
```

But I need the condition to return **false** if a user enters a search term that matches just a middle section of each substring.

I thought about using regex but I'm not sure how the expression would work for this use case.

Comment: I think the regex that you want is: (^k)|(?:\W)k|^s|(?:\W)s/gmi

Comment: https://regex101.com/

Comment: I am not sure if this is correct question on SO. But here the proposal from me. You already have a list of Strings on which you should return true. You can put them in a set and then check if this set contains your input String

Comment: @ControlAltDel  `/gmi` for java ? @roman_s is the *search term* given? (if the search term is  `s`, maybe the regex is `"(\\b| )\\Q" + s + "\\E"` or similar)

Comment: @user85421 re:/gmi - to appropriate a quote for The Karate Kid: "Regex do yes? ok Regex do no? ok. Regex just to get it to pass the unit testing? *Squish* just like bug" My original regex proposal should have had a / at the start

Comment: Can you provide more information about the _"search terms"_?  Why would _"i"_ return _false_?  If the the text ends with an _"i"_?

Comment: It's not clear to me how you decide what should be accepted and what not. Is this about word boundaries? Then check the `\b` regex special character. Also check [ask].

Answer (score 0):

It seems from your examples that a term should "match" if it's a case-insensitive substring of the search string and either:

- the first character is a non-letter, or
- it matches at the start of a word

You can use regex:

```
String search;
String term;

boolean match = search.matches(".*(?=\\W|\\b)\\Q" + term + "\\E.*");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @ControlAltDel I ended up using your regex with this java code.

```
String searchTerm = "siz";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(^" + searchTerm + ")|(?:\\W)"
+ searchTerm, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("KING-SIZE (KS)");

System.out.println(matcher.find());
// Outputs "true"
```

Feel free to post to your answer so I could mark it as solved

Comment: Don't forget to escape `searchTerm`: `Pattern.quote(searchTerm)`

Comment: Wow I didn't know about that. Thanks @MCEmperor I'll be using that